# Declare function pointer with variable args

Tags: c

How do I declare a pointer to a function with variable args?

e.g `int (*my_printf) (FILE *stream, const char *format, ..., void *data) = NULL;`

The error from clang was:

```
a.c:8:56: error: expected ')'
int (*my_printf) (FILE *stream, const char *format, ..., char *data) = NULL;
                                                       ^
a.c:8:18: note: to match this '('
int (*my_printf) (FILE *stream, const char *format, ..., char *data) = NULL;
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Of course, I could simple place the `data` parameter as the last one. But I still want a general solution

@Jim:

So, what do you think about `execle` function?

(From `man execle` I see this)

```
 int execle(const char *path, const char *arg,
              ..., char * const envp[]);
```

[image]

Comment: The ellipsis must be last, whether it's a function pointer or a function. Read the varargs documentation.

Comment: Hi @JimBalter, can you see my update about `execle`?

Comment: @warl0ck that's not the declaration found in the code though.  That's the definition used for documentation.

Comment: `cat /usr/include/unistd.h |grep execle` => `int execle(const char *, const char *, ...);` (OSX 10.9)

Comment: @randomusername is correct. You _should_ place the envp pointer last, but the type system has no clue about that and can't warn you if you don't do it.

Comment: @Guido you mean, envp is part of `...`, but should be the last one in the list?

Comment: Exactly, it's part of the variable arguments.

Comment: A man page is not a program and need not be syntactically correct. See http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/execle/ which goes out of its way to avoid being syntactically incorrect by using a comment, `/*, (char *)0, char *const envp[] */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ellipsis notation must be in the end, or it's undefined behavior.

> C11 §6.9.1 *Function definitions* Subsection 8
>
> If a function that accepts a variable number of arguments is defined without a parameter
> type list that ends with the ellipsis notation, the behavior is undefined.

As for the prototype of [`execle`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html), what you quote is incorrect, it should be:

```
int execle(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*,
   (char *)0, char *const envp[]*/);
```

Note that `envp` etc. are inside comments `/*  */`.

Comment: @warl0ck That prototype specifies _how_ you should use it, but it's not defined that way in the code. You can run `grep -rn execle /usr/include/` to see it.

Answer (score 4):

Ellipsis (`...`) must always be the last formal argument.